# Windows Phone 7 passing values between pages

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass the image value in one xaml page to another xaml page in windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213354/how-to-pass-the-image-value-in-one-xaml-page-to-another-xaml-page-in-windows-pho)
>   [Passing data from page to page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page)

I think is not a duplicate, because I dont found answer for my question, I dont passing an image, I passing 2darray[3,3] values in Page2.
I am developing a Windows Phone 7 app. I have two pages (mainpage and page2). I wrote the code in the mainpage. I have a 2D array with values. How can I use this array in page2? Please give a step by step answer, I am a beginner.

Comment: This has been asked many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953491/passing-data-from-page-to-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON to serialize your array. You can use [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) like I did. Remember that you cannot pass every string to your Uri - if it contains characters like **'&'** your app will crash. That's why you have to use **Uri.UnescapeDataString**.

This an example for 2D string array. If you need to pass complex objects it's still possible to use JSON.net (see the documentation). Just remember to use **Uri.UnescapeDataString** after serialization.

**Before** you deserialize your array from JSON you have to unescape it (**Uri.UnescapeDataString**).

In your source page:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public static class Extensions
    {

        public static string GetHtmlDecoded(this string str)
        {
            return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(str);
        }

        public static string GetHtmlEncoded(this string str)
        {
            return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(str);
        }

    }

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            var arrStr = new[,]
                {
                    {"aaaa$ffeaw&fewa=324&fewa", "fewa"},
                    {"aafw&fewa=324&fewa", "fefewa"},
                };


            string param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrStr);
            param = Uri.EscapeDataString( param);

            var destination = new Uri("/Page1.xaml?arr=" + param, UriKind.Relative);
            NavigationService.Navigate(destination );
        }
    }
}
```

In the destination page:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace PhoneApp2
{
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
            var param = Uri.UnescapeDataString(NavigationContext.QueryString["arr"]);
            var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[,]>(param);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `-1` for syntax errors, and not even addressing the issue of serializing a 2D array as a query string parameter.

Comment: @MikeChristensen You're right I was a little messy. I fixed it. :)

Comment: @user2040397 btw the easiest way to reference to the JSON.net and many other libraries would be through Nuget. Read about it if haven't used it before.

Comment: I installed Json package. I wrote it. But I dont know how to use my arrays in destination page.  My arrays name: racs[3,3] and it is a string. So example I would like that: TextBox.Text = racs[1,2] in the destination Page.

Comment: @user2040397 You cannot call Text property on TextBox class. You have to call it on your object. Like that: myTextBox.Text=racs[1,2]; Comments is not the right place for this discussion. I suggest you read a tutorial on windows phone and if something is still unclear ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Windows Phone 7 (yet), but I would imagine it is possible to declare a public property on Page2 and populate it with the array after creation.

Comment: Can you write it step by step? Thanks.