# reading from text box and passing to another page

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, textbox

I want to read text from TextBox and then send it to another page. But on another page I keep geting empty string.
why this doesn't work ?

I have this on page 1:

```
public string _beseda()
{
    return textBox1.Text;          
}
```

and on page 2 where I should retrieve this string:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Page2 neki = new Page2();
    MessageBox.Show(neki._beseda());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two strategies to pass data between pages in windows phone.

1. Use App.cs
2. Pass data as parameter values during navigation

**1. Using App.cs**

Open up App.cs code behind of App.xaml write:

```
 // To store Textbox the value   
 public string storeValue;
```

In Page1

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        App app = Application.Current  as App;
        app.storeValue = textBox1.Text;            
    }
```

on Page2

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    App app = Application.Current  as App;
    MessageBox.Show(app.storeValue);
}
```

**2. Passing values as parameters while navigating**

Before navigating embed textbox value to the Page Url

```
    string newUrl = "/Page2.xaml?text="+textBox1.Text;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(newUrl, UriKind.Relative));
```

in Page2

```
    //Temporarily hold the value got from the navigation 
    string textBoxValue = "";
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        //Retrieve the value passed during page navigation
         NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("text", out textBoxValue)               
    }


     private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

       MessageBox.Show(textBoxValue);
     }
```

Here are a number of useful links..

- [How to pass the image value in one xaml page to another xaml page in
  windows phone 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213354/how-to-pass-the-image-value-in-one-xaml-page-to-another-xaml-page-in-windows-phon)
- [How to perform page navigation on Windows
  Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626521%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot, I know it's kind of basic Q but I'm new to this, so thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of issues. You say you have that `_beseda()` function on `Page1`, but you reference `Page2()` in `button1_click()`. Additionally, if I assume you meant `Page1` in `button1_click()`, you're creating new`Page1` and then you ask it for the text box's text.... so of course it's empty. You haven't put anything in it.

Even if you meant to put `Page2` there instead, the problem is still the same.